# Accessing list elements versus dict keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I recently wrote some code that accesses elements in a list of lists (which I created), and passes those elements to other methods to handle tasks. In a code review, I was informed that rather than accessing elements the way by index in a list, a dict may be better since I don't need to rely on an index. Although this was a personal preference of my colleague, I'm curious to know if there are any tech reasons why this would be ideal. I understand this argument if the list would not always contain the expected amount of elements, but since the data was coming from a data file and I know all elements will be present, I decided to use a list. Example below:

```
data = [
  [
   item0,
   item1,
   item2,
  ],
...
]
```

```
other_arg = something
for item in data:
  other_method(other_arg, item[1], item[2])
```

So I'm curious to better understand the differences in why it may be better practice to access elements using a `key` instead of an `index`, or vice versa. Appreciate any responses.

Comment: Was it informed to convert the list of lists to a list of dictionaries?

Comment: @Rohith Yeah it was, I misunderstood this approach for the reason that I had control over the list that I was creating, but after pairing with my colleague we were able to have this conversation regarding why it's overall best practice to use a dictionary rather than a list with indexes, so that anyone who uses my code or reviews it will understand exactly what those items are without needing to further examine the rest of my code to understand what those arguments are. Example: `dict['character']` over `item[0]`